# Finite and infinite geometric series / power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-series

In a problem I have both $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a^n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{S}{a^n}$ (finite and infinite). To simplify I found that the infinite summation is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a^n} = \dfrac{1}{1-a}$$

But for the finite summation I found two different results (notice that both start at zero):

1. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Ba%5En,%20%7Bn,%200,%20infinity%7D%5D): $\sum_{n=0}^{S}{a^n} = \dfrac{a^{S+1}-1}{a-1} \tag{1}$
2. And here: $\sum_{n=0}^{S}{a^n} = \dfrac{1-a^{S+1}}{1-a} \tag{2}$ (mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html)

($a$ fulfills the condition $|a|\lt 1$)

According to my math the two are not equivalent, **Which is the correct one?**

I also need formulas for both, finite and infinite, of this serie $\sum_{n=0}{n \cdot a^n}$ (both starting at zero). [In wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bn*%20a%5En,%20%7Bn,%200,%20Infinity%7D%5D) I found that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n \cdot a^n} = \dfrac{a}{(a-1)^2} \tag{3}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^{S}{n \cdot a^n} = \dfrac{(a \cdot S - S - 1) \cdot a^{S + 1} + a}{(1-a)^2} \tag{4}$$

**Are these correct? And, how are these last series called?** I'd like to see a proof but I didn't know the name to look for.

Thanks.

EDIT: I fixed (1).

Comment: The formula you posted under **1.** is wrong, and doesn't match what the link to Wolfram Alpha shows, either. Please edit and clarify the question.

Comment: @dxiv you were right, I fixed the formula now. Still, it's different, I don't know which, (1) or (2) is the right one. Both are very similar.

Comment: They are *not* different any longer now. Consider that $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{-x}{-y}$.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!
Do you know about (3) and (4)?

Comment: Lookup power sums for a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. I found the general formula, and from there I was able to determine if (3) and (4) are correct, and they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a^n} = \dfrac{1-a^{N+1}}{1-a}$ This is true as long as $a \ne 1$.

Now consider $|a|<1$, and let $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Then $a^N \rightarrow 0$, so

$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N}{a^n} = \dfrac{1-a^{N+1}}{1-a}=\dfrac{1}{1-a}.$

The last variations can be shown by induction or by using calculus.

[1] is wrong, but you can fix it by starting the summation at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{S}{a^n} = \dfrac{a (a^S-1)}{(a-1)}$.